# simulate the contiguous file allocation

Tags: c, operating-system

I've been trying to solve this question:

Write source code in C to simulate the contiguous file allocation with the following conditions:

prompt the user to enter the number of files
enter the name of the file
enter the starting block number
enter the number of blocks occupied by the file
And the condition is: ( No two files must have the same block " if the user enters the same block not being present in the previous file, prompt the user Block already in use " )

the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct
{
    char fname[10];
} f[10];

main()
{
    int n,i,j,b[20],sb[20],t[20],x,c[20][20];
    printf("Enter no. of files: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter file %d name: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", f[i].fname);
        printf("Enter no. of blocks occupied by file %s: ",f[i].fname);
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
        printf("Enter the starting block of file %s: ",f[i].fname);
        scanf("%d",&sb[i]);
        t[i]=sb[i];
        for(j=0;j<b[i];j++)
            c[i][j]=sb[i]++;
    }
    
    printf("Filename\tStart block\tlength\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%s\t %d \t%d\n",f[i].fname,t[i],b[i]);
    printf("blocks occupiedate:\n");
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("file name %s ",f[i].fname);
        for(j=0;j<b[i];j++)
            printf("\t%d",c[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

MY PROBLEM IS:

I don't know what "IF CONDITION" should i write to know if the block is occupied or not ??? Like what are we comparing here ? Because I've been trying all day long and i still couldn't figure it out !

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Each time a new file is entered, you will know it occupies blocks from START to START+LENGTH-1; let's call that the "extent" of the file. Your job is to track the extents of all files so far entered into your program, and check each file against all of the preceding ones.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me out, but can you explain more briefly please :( im having a hard time trying to figure out the " if " condition im supposed to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is rather hard to follow, in part because of single-letter variable names, but it seems you're storing the starting block and length for the i'th file in sb[i] and b[i].

Assuming that to be the case, when the i'th file details are entered, you need to check whether it overlaps any of the previous i-1 files.

```
// compare i'th file against all previous files, in turn.
overlap = false;
for (k=0; k<i-1; k++) {
    if (sb[i] >= sb[k] && sb[i] < sb[k] + b[k]) {
        // start of i'th file is inside k'th file
        overlap = true;
        break;
    }
    if (sb[i] + b[i] >= sb[k] && sb[i] + b[i] < sb[k] + b[k]) {
        // end of i'th file is inside k'th file
        overlap = true;
        break;
    }
}

// if overlap is true here, then reject the current file details
```

---

I typed this off the top of my head, so you should check it carefully, in particular the edge conditions (like, did I use less-than versus less-or-equal correctly?).  Validation is left as an exercise for the student, as they say in all the best textbooks.

You might also check I understood the terms of the question ;-)
I see what might (in the array `c[][]`) be an attempt at an allocation bitmap, which admittedly might be more in the spirit of 'simulated file system' (no file system compares a new-file creation against all existing files), so perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree-structure.  If so, you'll need to fill in more details of the question.